# Compute the Bias of the estimates

Tags: probability, statistics, regression, linear-regression

If the true expection of response is
\begin{align}
E(y)=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\beta_2x^2
\end{align}
but you assume $E(y)=\beta_0+\beta_1x$ insted. With $x=-2,-1,0,1,2$. How can i compute the Bias of the estimates of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$?. I did sth wrong because my solution is 0. Pls support me. Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you simply ignore the $\beta_2$ term but kept the correct $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ terms then you would be $\beta_2\times 4$ too low for $x=-2$, $\beta_2\times 1$ too low for $x=-1$, $\beta_2\times 0$ too low for $x=0$, $\beta_2\times 1$ too low for $x=1$, and  $\beta_2\times 4$ too low for $x=2$.

Your linear regression will attempt to minimise these errors.  The best fit to $(-2,4\beta_2),  (-1,\beta_2),  (0,0),  (1,\beta_2), (2,4\beta_2)$ would be $\hat y=2\beta_2 +0x$

so the expected bias in the estimate of $\beta_0$ is $2\beta_2$, and the expected bias in the estimate of $\beta_1$ is $0$.